# Scala check if object is an Option or not

Tags: scala, monads

I would like to check if an object is an option.

For example:

```
val foo: Option[String] = Some("foo")
val bar: String = "bar"
```

I would like a function kind of `isOption`:

```
def isOption(value: Any): Boolean = {
     ???
}
```

And the result will be:

```
isOption(foo) // true
isOption(bar) // false
```

Comment: Please refer to documentation first: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html or https://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_options.htm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can write your function as

```
def isOption(value: Any): Boolean = {
  value match {
    case x : Option[_] => true
    case _ => false
  }
}
```

On invoking the function

```
val foo: Option[String] = Some("foo")
val bar: String = "bar"
```

you will get an output as

```
res0: Boolean = true
res1: Boolean = false
```

Answer (score 5):

A short solution would be

```
value.isInstanceOf[Option[_]]
```

This also wouldn't obfuscate the fact that you have essentially untyped `Any`-values and `instanceof`'s flying around in your code, which should be avoided, if possible.